# Is a GET request still idempotent if it is cached?

Tags: api, get, api-design, idempotent

My understanding is that an idempotent request doesn't change anything.  If there are side effects generated by a GET request (for instance, caching a request to a search endpoint), is it still idempotent?

Answer (score 2):

For an action to be idempotent you must be able to repeat it without causing additional side-effects.

In your specific example, if a GET request is causing data to be fetched from an external source then the question is really about the idempotency of that source, though given you mention a search endpoint the chances are it will be.

Idempotency in this scenario doesn't guarantee that the results that you'll get back are identical each time, just that you can call the endpoint as many times as you want without affecting the system.

Edit: A counter example: if the GET endpoint was causing data to get de-queued, i.e. removed from the system such that it couldn't be retrieved again, then this would *not* be idempotent.

Comment: Sorry, I left out one important word in my question ("_caching_ a request to an endpoint").  But it seems like you're saying that idempotency is in the eye of the beholder - that it is more about the data returned to the requestor; that the state of the system serving the api is not *necessarily* what defines idempotency?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

In the description, the caching is in the service implementation, not at GET level or some middle.

The side effect is internal to the service, it does not change the results that will be returned with subsequent calls.

Some background under GET at http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html